# Get Gradients with Keras Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard, tensorflow2.0

I would like to keep track of the **gradients** over tensorboard.
However, since session run statements are not a thing anymore and the *write_grads* argument of *tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard* is **deprecated**, I would like to know how to keep track of gradients during training with **Keras** or **tensorflow 2.0**.

My current approach is to create a new callback class for this purpose, but without success. Maybe someone else knows how to accomplish this kind of advanced stuff.

The code created for testing is shown below, but runs into errors independently of printing a gradient value to console or tensorboard.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', name='dense128'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='dense10')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


class GradientCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    console = True

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        weights = [w for w in self.model.trainable_weights if 'dense' in w.name and 'bias' in w.name]
        loss = self.model.total_loss
        optimizer = self.model.optimizer
        gradients = optimizer.get_gradients(loss, weights)
        for t in gradients:
            if self.console:
                print('Tensor: {}'.format(t.name))
                print('{}\n'.format(K.get_value(t)[:10]))
            else:
                tf.summary.histogram(t.name, data=t)


file_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer("./metrics")
file_writer.set_as_default()

# write_grads has been removed
tensorboard_cb = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(histogram_freq=1, write_grads=True)
gradient_cb = GradientCallback()

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, callbacks=[gradient_cb, tensorboard_cb])
```

- Priniting bias gradients to console (console parameter = True)
  leads to: **AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'**
- Writing to tensorboard (console parameter = False) creates:
  **TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the
  value of a tensor.**

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if 'dense' in w.name or 'bias' in w.name`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To compute the gradients of the loss against the weights, use

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    loss = model(model.trainable_weights)

tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_weights)
```

This is (arguably poorly) documented on [GradientTape](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape).

We do not need to `tape.watch` the variable because trainable parameters are watched by default.

As a function, it can be written as

```
def gradient(model, x):
    x_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(x, dtype=tf.float32)
    with tf.GradientTape() as t:
        t.watch(x_tensor)
        loss = model(x_tensor)
    return t.gradient(loss, x_tensor).numpy()
```

Comment: Should it not be:

`with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    loss = model(input)`

Comment: model() return prediction rather than loss.

Comment: Er, can we merge that with `keras.Model.fit` and `keras.callbacks`? Thanks!

Comment: Should this function be called from the callback?

Comment: Also if called from `on_epoch_end` what is `x`?

Comment: I am not making this work, on the first code... you call the model using the weights? where is the input? On the second, how can x_tensor give the loss, where are the labels? I get nothing.

Answer (score 6):

Also have a look here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31542#issuecomment-630495970

*richardwth* wrote a child class of Tensorboard.

I adapted it as follows:

```
class ExtendedTensorBoard(tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard):
    def _log_gradients(self, epoch):
        writer = self._writers['train']

        with writer.as_default(), tf.GradientTape() as g:
            # here we use test data to calculate the gradients
            features, y_true = list(val_dataset.batch(100).take(1))[0]

            y_pred = self.model(features)  # forward-propagation
            loss = self.model.compiled_loss(y_true=y_true, y_pred=y_pred)  # calculate loss
            gradients = g.gradient(loss, self.model.trainable_weights)  # back-propagation

            # In eager mode, grads does not have name, so we get names from model.trainable_weights
            for weights, grads in zip(self.model.trainable_weights, gradients):
                tf.summary.histogram(
                    weights.name.replace(':', '_') + '_grads', data=grads, step=epoch)

        writer.flush()

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        # This function overwrites the on_epoch_end in tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard
        # but we do need to run the original on_epoch_end, so here we use the super function.
        super(ExtendedTensorBoard, self).on_epoch_end(epoch, logs=logs)

        if self.histogram_freq and epoch % self.histogram_freq == 0:
            self._log_gradients(epoch)
```

Comment: I am getting: `AttributeError: 'ExtendedTensorBoard' object has no attribute '_get_writer'`

Comment: I found the solution, change by line `writer = self._writers['train']`. Maybe update the answer? It would be nice to know since wich version this changed.

Comment: @AgustinBarrachina I updated the answer based on your comment.

Comment: With TF2.x one can subclass `tf.keras.models.Model` and inside `GradientTape` scope, writing computed gradients to some intermediate metrics; then from inside a custom Callback (TensorBoard in this context), access that metrics and write to file. This way the gradient is computed only once, saving time.