# tensorflow v2 gradients not shown on tensorboard histograms

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorboard, gradienttape

I have a simple neural network for which I am trying to plot the gradients using tensorboard by using  a callback as below:

```
class GradientCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    console = False
    count = 0
    run_count = 0

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        weights = [w for w in self.model.trainable_weights if 'dense' in w.name and 'bias' in w.name]
        self.run_count += 1
        run_dir = logdir+"/gradients/run-" + str(self.run_count)
        with tf.summary.create_file_writer(run_dir).as_default(),tf.GradientTape() as g:
          # use test data to calculate the gradients
          _x_batch = test_images_scaled_reshaped[:100]
          _y_batch = test_labels_enc[:100]
          g.watch(_x_batch)
          _y_pred = self.model(_x_batch)  # forward-propagation
          per_sample_losses = tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(_y_batch, _y_pred) 
          average_loss = tf.reduce_mean(per_sample_losses) # Compute the loss value
          gradients = g.gradient(average_loss, self.model.weights) # Compute the gradient

        for t in gradients:
          tf.summary.histogram(str(self.count), data=t)
          self.count+=1
          if self.console:
                print('Tensor: {}'.format(t.name))
                print('{}\n'.format(K.get_value(t)[:10]))

# Set up logging
!rm -rf ./logs/ # clear old logs
from datetime import datetime
import os
root_logdir = "logs"
run_id = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
logdir = os.path.join(root_logdir, run_id)


# register callbacks, this will be used for tensor board latter
callbacks = [
    tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard( log_dir=logdir, histogram_freq=1, 
                                   write_images=True, write_grads = True ),
    GradientCallback()
]
```

Then,I use the callbacks during fit as:

```
network.fit(train_pipe, epochs = epochs,batch_size = batch_size, validation_data = val_pipe, callbacks=callbacks)
```

Now, when I check the tensorboard, I get to see gradients on the left side filter but nothing shows up in the Histogram tab:

[image: Histogram tensorboard gradients]

What am I missing here? Am I logging the gradients correctly?

Comment: Is your question resolved now ? Else, please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64062465/14290681),may helps you.

Comment: That link uses Tensorflow 1.x

Comment: Hi, I am trying to do the same thing: did u come to grips with this? Any solution? I am trying to do the same thing there is not much around about it.

Comment: Hey sorry, haven't found any solution to this. Wish there was better documentation around it.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the issue is that you write your histograms outside the context of the tf summary writer.
I changed your code accordingly. But I didn't try it out.

```
class GradientCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    console = False
    count = 0
    run_count = 0

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        weights = [w for w in self.model.trainable_weights if 'dense' in w.name and 'bias' in w.name]
        self.run_count += 1
        run_dir = logdir+"/gradients/run-" + str(self.run_count)
        with tf.summary.create_file_writer(run_dir).as_default()
          with tf.GradientTape() as g:
            # use test data to calculate the gradients
            _x_batch = test_images_scaled_reshaped[:100]
            _y_batch = test_labels_enc[:100]
            g.watch(_x_batch)
            _y_pred = self.model(_x_batch)  # forward-propagation
            per_sample_losses = tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(_y_batch, _y_pred) 
            average_loss = tf.reduce_mean(per_sample_losses) # Compute the loss value
            gradients = g.gradient(average_loss, self.model.weights) # Compute the gradient

          for nr, grad in enumerate(gradients):
            tf.summary.histogram(str(nr), data=grad)
            if self.console:
                  print('Tensor: {}'.format(grad.name))
                  print('{}\n'.format(K.get_value(grad)[:10]))
```

Comment: Getting `ValueError: Passed in object of type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, not tf.Tensor` error

Comment: @shaikmoeed most likely your data (_x_batch, _y_batch) is a numpy array not a tf.Tensor. You need to convert it before you can use it in this context. The solution I proposed only fixes the problem of the gradients not being sent to tensorboard. Any other problems with the code are out of scope for the answer.

Comment: I would like similar behavior and trying to use your code but do not understand where test_images_scaled_reshaped[:100] is coming from? Since the function is applied at epoch end wouldn't you want to get the train data corresponding to that epoch?